# How do I use node Promise and http together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to learn about Promises in node.  I want to be able to use the http.request as a promise.  This is what I have learnt so far.

I set up a test case using setTimeout as shown below:

```
var makePromise = (txt, milli) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {  // fn(cb)
            console.log("I promise to...")
            resolve(txt)
        }, milli)
    });
}

var p = makePromise("Come Home", 3000);
var q = makePromise("Go Shopping", 1000);

var tasks = [p, q];

console.log("Start with ", tasks);

Promise.all(tasks).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log("Finish");
})
```

This works fine.  Now I thought that all I would need to do was replace the setTimeout function with the appropriate http.request.  But it doesn't seem to be as straightforward as that.

Here is the current attempt at this.

```
var makePromise = (collection, item) => {
    var options = {
        method: "PUT",
        port: 9000,
        host: "localhost",
        path: `/${collection}/item/${item.Label.itemUUID}`,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Content-length": JSON.stringify(req.body).length
        }
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(options));

    var httpPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var vot = http.request(options, (votResponse) => {
            var responseBody = [];
            votResponse.on('data', (chunk) => {
                console.log(`Got ${chunk.length} ${chunk}`);
                responseBody.push(chunk);
            });
            votResponse.on('end', () => {
                console.log("End of http");
                console.log("After web proxy like call - raw data: ", Buffer.concat(responseBody).toString());
                responseBody.json = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(responseBody).toString());
                resolve(responseBody.json);
            });
            votResponse.on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        })
        vot.write(JSON.stringify(item));
        vot.end();
    });
    return httpPromise;
};
```

I know there are libraries like "request-promise" that can help, but I am keen to get a deeper understanding of the native operations before using a library.  Can anyone point out how I might get this approach to work?

The calling code is shown here:

```
var collection = req.params.collection;
var patchInstruction = req.body.patchInstruction;
switch (patchInstruction) {
    case "CASCADE DELETE": 
        console.log("CASCADE DELETE on", collection, req.body.item);
        var tasks = [req.body.item].concat(req.body.asSubject).concat(req.body.asObject);
        tasks = tasks.map((e, i, a) => {
            e.Item = "DELETED"
            return makeDeletePromise(collection, e); // a promise to do the http PUT
        });
        console.log("WIP ", tasks);
        Promise.all(tasks).then((res) => {
            console.log("To client --> ",res);
            res.send(res);  
        })
        break;
    default:    
        console.log("No path to ",patchInstruction);
        res.send(409);
        break;
}
```

The call to port 9000 never happens.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Added the calling code.

Comment: You can just look at the source code for request promise here: https://github.com/request/request-promise/blob/master/lib/rp.js

Comment: Your calling code looks like it sometimes returns a promise and sometimes returns nothing.  It is unclear how that would be good or useful.  Other than that, I can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to end a promise chain with a `catch` call. Otherwise, any error that happens inside a promise chain would be "swallowed" -- you simply will not see it.

So, any time there is a `then` there should be a `catch`.

```
Promise.all(tasks).then((res) => {
    console.log("To client --> ", res);
    res.send(res);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I believe, an error is somewhere near `res.send(res)`, because http's `res` is shadowed by local `res`. Which is really a `responseBody.json`, so it has no `send` method.